# After enabling HTTP/2 I get SSL handshake mismatch

Tags: ios, nginx, openssl

I run a Centos 7 server with directadmin. According to the instructions provided by them I installed openssl 1.1.0 and nginx 1.11.3 together with the http/2 module. Other than that I have not changed any SSLCiphers or whatsoever. For the SSL certificate I use Letsencrypt which worked without problems before the switch to HTTP/2 (well it does now too, just not on IOS).

When I enable http2 in the nginx config: people with an Iphone 6S and Ipad Air2 cannot visit my server (nginx error 502) and in the server logs I find the following error:

```
2016/09/13 19:17:09 [crit] 29560#0: *1846 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1417D18C:SSL routines:tls_process_client_hello:version too low) while SSL handshaking, client: 64.xxx, server: 178.xxx:443
2016/09/13 19:19:07 [crit] 29560#0: *3040 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1417D18C:SSL routines:tls_process_client_hello:version too low) while SSL handshaking, client: 64.xxx, server: 178.xxx:443
2016/09/13 19:31:28 [crit] 29559#0: *19502 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1417D18C:SSL routines:tls_process_client_hello:version too low) while SSL handshaking, client: 64.xxx, server: 178.xxx:443
2016/09/13 19:33:27 [crit] 31669#0: *21281 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1417D18C:SSL routines:tls_process_client_hello:version too low) while SSL handshaking, client: 64.xxx, server: 178.xxx:443
2016/09/13 19:34:12 [crit] 32619#0: *21862 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1417D18C:SSL routines:tls_process_client_hello:version too low) while SSL handshaking, client: 64.xxx, server: 178.xxx:443
2016/09/13 19:36:10 [crit] 32620#0: *23890 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1417D18C:SSL routines:tls_process_client_hello:version too low) while SSL handshaking, client: 64.xxx, server: 178.xxx:443
```

The weird thing is I have a mirror server where I 'try out things' and doing exactly the same on that server doesn't jinx the connection with the Ipad/phones.

I'm having difficulties troubleshooting this one. Any help?

Edit: it seems to be a problem with IOS 9 (6, 7, 8 are fine...)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Okay, I'll post the question elswhere.